# VTiger beginner - where are these items?

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger

I am a beginner to Vtiger and I want to get a modification done. I need to understand the order of Vtiger functions.

So here are my questions:

1. What folder contains the bulk of the PHP functions? (Ex. vlib?), I searched all of the module files, these seem to call function included from somewhere else.

   To better define why I need to understand these locations, here is what I want to do: I need to modify the line items of a Product or Service in a Quote by adding a field. (I have already added the field to my MySQL table).
2. Where is the folder that contains the "update" function for Products and Services?
   Next I need the new information to appear on the quote output to PDF.
3. Where is the folder that contains the quote query function?

I seek answers that might help anyone who reads this speed up their learning curve of the Vtiger architecture, I do not expect anyone to do the work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tool help add fields and blocks:

http://vtiger-crm.2324883.n4.nabble.com/Vtigercrm-developers-Module-Designer-for-Vtiger-6-td8893.html#none

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about all of your questions, i'm a vtiger newbie too, but vtlib library examples are located in `/vtigerrootinstallation/vtlib/vtliblibraryversion`, are you on windows or linux?

Comment: I have learned that Products and Services are really inventory. To find the line items on the Quote has been difficult. BUT I have located the Product/Service line items for the layout only in the  .../layouts/modules/inventory  folder. I am now seeking the Quote functions that output to PDF

Answer (score 0):

After little help from Wiki or the documentation, I did finally find a good answer here: 
[Adding fields to Line Items](https://discussions.vtiger.com/index.php?p=/discussion/51712/problems-adding-fields-to-line-items-in-quotes/p1)

Here is the "list", its a great starter to learn the location of items

> I've solved the issue!!! I can now insert fields into line items for
>   quotes and sales orders and successfully store and retrieve them from
>   the vtiger database. Here is a basic overview of what I did to add
>   this functionality (which has been quite the learning process).
>
> Alter the following table and add your new fields to it:
>
> - vtiger_inventoryproductrel
>
> The following files were modified:
>
> - include\js\Inventory.js - Retrieves data from the DB
> - include\utils\DetailViewUtils.php -Retrieves data from DB
> - include\utils\EditViewUtils.php - Writes data to DB
> - include\utils\InventoryUtils.php - Writes data to DB
> - Smarty\templates\Inventory\ProductDetails.tpl -fromats new fields for  display view
> - Smarty\templates\Inventory\ProductDetailsEditView.tpl -   formats new fields in edit view
> - include\language\en_us.lang.php -    Holds new labels for new fields

Again this is not a full solution but does provide location and direction